# iOS Google Drive SDK Integration

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-drive-api

I am integrating google drive SDK in my iPhone app. I am trying to upload file inside a folder by using the following method

```
-(void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString *)path atIndexid:(int)indexId{

   GTLDriveFile *parentRefFile=[driveFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexId];
   if ([parentRefFile.mimeType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"]) {

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    NSLog(@"path--str------%@",path);

    if (fileHandle) {
        GTLServiceDrive *service = [self createServiceDriveObj];

        GTLDriveChildReference *childRef=[GTLDriveChildReference object];
        childRef.childLink=path;
        childRef.kind=@"drive#childReference";
        GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenInsertWithObject:childRef folderId:parentRefFile.identifier];


        ticket= [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                        GTLDriveFile *uploadedFile,
                                                        NSError *error) {
            // Callback
            if (error == nil) {
                [_delegate didFinishUploadingFileAtPath:path ForTheObject:_delegate];

            } else {
                [_delegate didFailedToUploadFileAtPath:path withError:error ForTheObject:_delegate];
            }
        }];

    } else {
        // Could not read file data.
        [self displayAlert:@"No Upload File Found" format:@"Path: %@", path];
    }
}
else {
    [self displayAlert:@"File type you have choosen is not a folder" format:nil];
}
```

}

When i call the above method to upload, i am getting the following error message 
**The operation couldn’t be completed. (Resource metadata required)**. I am not sure what i am missing. If i want to set identifier property of the GTLChildReference object, i am not sure what to set for that property.Please help me

Comment: I have same problem with insert Parent to exsisted file by manual post request.